# Angular ui-router url issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a search form, something like (jade):

```
div.search
   form.form-inline(role="form", method="get", ng-controller="searchFormController")
    div.row
     div.col-xs-2
      h3 Search
     div.col-xs-8
       input.form-control.input-lg(ng-model="searchTerm", ng-change="changed()", type='text' ,name="search" ,placeholder='enter your search ')#search
       |Your search terms:{{searchTerm}}
     div.col-xs-2
       a.btn.btn-danger.btn-lg(href="#/search")#searchSubmit Search 
  div.search_results(ui-view)
```

My ui-router config has something like :

```
$stateProvider
    .state('search', {
        url:'/search',
        templateUrl:'templates/search.html'
    })
```

This loads `search.html` which has a controller that loads the results as `JSON`. The problem I am having is that this only works once, i.e I cannot click the search button more than once to get a new set of results. Furthermore, if for some reason the page on which this is located has a url without the last '/' the search is also not loaded.

(1) how do I ensure that this would work for both `localhost:3000` and `localhost:3000\`
(2) is there some way I can clear the url so that `href=!"#/search"` works multiple times ?

Comment: might be something to do with `ng-href`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass search value as GET param, and read it in controller.

Search button:

```
<button type="submit" url="'#/home/search/?phrase={{queryString}}'"></button>
```

In controller read 'phrase' value by using `$location` service

```
app.controller('searchResults', function ($scope, $location, $http) {
    $scope.queryString = $location.search().phrase;

});
```

For more look at `$location` specification [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location)